# How to select only one record of each category?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Products :
--------------------------------------------
|   ID   |   Group   |   Name   |   Sold   |
--------------------------------------------
|   1    |     A     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   2    |     A     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   3    |     B     |   Dell   |    1     |
--------------------------------------------
|   4    |     B     |   Dell   |    1     |
--------------------------------------------
|   5    |     C     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   6    |     C     |   Dell   |    1     |
--------------------------------------------
```

Hi everyone, i have a table (products) stored in MySql with many records, for now i'm using this query `SELECT * FROM products WHERE sold = 0`, in results i get :

```
--------------------------------------------
|   ID   |   Group   |   Name   |   Sold   |
--------------------------------------------
|   1    |     A     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   2    |     A     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   5    |     C     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
```

i want to get only one record from each group, so the results will be like :

```
--------------------------------------------
|   ID   |   Group   |   Name   |   Sold   |
--------------------------------------------
|   1    |     A     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
|   5    |     C     |   Dell   |    0     |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So even though A has 2 sold, you want only the first found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the statement **GROUP BY**,

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE sold = 0 GROUP BY group
```

in the results now, i get only one record for each group and the minimal id without adding any other statement, and in my real table i am using **product_group** instead of **group** because it's a reserved word.

Comment: what do I do when I want 2 records of each category?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this by using a `distinct` clause and removing the `id` column. If you want to keep the `id` column you need to specify how one would chose which `id` to keep.

```
select distinct
  `group`
  , name
  , sold
from
  products
where
  sold = 0;
```

To keep the row with the smallest `id` (as your example shows) something along the lines of the example below would work.

```
select
  id
  , `group`
  , name
  , sold
from
  products
where
  sold = 0
  and id = (
    select
      min(p.id)
    from
      products p
    where
      p.`group`    = products.`group`
      and p.sold = 0
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your field named `Group` to something like `Group_Name`. GROUP is a reserved keyword, and if it is not causing you problems now it probably will later.

Second, you should ask yourself what you are really after. The following query should generate your desired result. It adds an additional condition where the IDs that are returned are the lowest numbered ID in each group.

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE sold = 0
      AND ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM products WHERE sold = 0 GROUP BY Group_Name)
```

Why do you want that, though? That is not a normal desired end state. You should ask yourself why you care about the ID. It looks like your goal is to figure out which products have not sold anything. In that case, I would recommend this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Group_Name, Name 
FROM products 
WHERE sold = 0 
ORDER BY Group_Name, Name
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT `ID`, `Group`, `Name`, `Sold`  FROM products WHERE sold = 0 GROUP BY `Group`;
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `group by` like that.

Comment: why so? could you please explain?

Comment: Because `group by` causes aggregation. And the selected columns should either be in the `group by` clause OR have aggregate functions applied. Failing to do so, like you did, leaves the returned values up to chance 
(there's no way of predicting which values will be returned) Also, see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: Check my answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697469/mysql-what-happens-to-non-aggregated-fields-upon-a-group-by/31697752#31697752 It goes a bit in depth