# One row per group with multiple column sorting

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, limit-per-group

Would like to return one row per group, where the one is selected by multiple sort columns. Treading lightly here in the land of [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) to avoid a duplicate question.

**SCHEMA:**

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  ip_address INT NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY id
);
```

**DATA:**

```
INSERT INTO logs (id, ip_address, status) 
VALUES ('1', 19216800, 1),
       ('2', 19216801, 2),
       ('3', 19216800, 2),
       ('4', 19216803, 0),
       ('5', 19216804, 0),
       ('6', 19216803, 0),
       ('7', 19216804, 1);
```

**CURRENT QUERY:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM logs
 ORDER BY ip_address, status=1 DESC, id DESC
```

Note: sorting by `status=1` effectively turns the status column into a boolean. The tie breaker after `status=1` is `id`. This query currently returns the correct row for each `ip_address` first and then a bunch of other rows I don't want for that `ip_address`.

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
1, 19216800, 1
3, 19216800, 2
2, 19216801, 2
6, 19216803, 0
4, 19216803, 0
7, 19216804, 1
5, 19216804, 0
```

**WANTED OUTPUT:**

```
1, 19216800, 1
2, 19216801, 2
6, 19216803, 0
7, 19216804, 1
```

---

Today my workaround is to filter in PHP with `if ($lastIP == $row['ip_address']) continue;`. But I would like to move this logic to MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry good call, thanks. I have added current output of the query and wanted output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT MIN(id), ip_address, status
FROM logs
GROUP BY ip_address, status
```

Comment: So basically this gets the right `id` for each ip_address for the true and false values of `status='completed'`. Thank you, this is very close since I would like to get it down to one row per `ip_address`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are already hundreds of solutions for greatest-n-per-group problems in MySQL, I'm going to start answering these questions with CTE syntax with window functions, since that is now available in MySQL 8.0.3.

```
WITH sorted AS (
    SELECT id, ip_address, status, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ip_address ORDER BY status) AS rn
    FROM logs
)
SELECT * FROM sorted WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice long term solution. I hope we can use this someday soon!

Comment: When 8.0 is released GA, I'll go back and edit my most popular greatest-n-per-group answers to add a CTE solution.

Comment: To be clear, I have not seen a solution yet to this particular question. Do you know of one that works without CTE? Asking because CTE is not yet in RHEL.

Comment: @FullDecent, just follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag and you'll find many solutions.

Comment: I will be happy to close this question as duplicate but I failed to find someone else that is looking for "first row with multiple column sorts". I saw plenty of questions looking for MAX(post_id) for each user but those are much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is different way to think about the problem. You want to find the "best" row for each `id_address`. Or in other words, you want to select rows where no better row exists.

This solution works for MySQL versions before 8.0. In other words, it works with the version you already have installed with RHEL 7. You can extend this technique easily for an arbitrary number of sort columns.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT * FROM logs) a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM logs) b
    ON (b.ip_address = a.ip_address AND (b.stat=1) > (a.stat=1))
    OR (b.ip_address = a.ip_address AND (b.stat=1) = (a.stat=1) AND b.id > a.id)
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
 ORDER BY a.ip_address
```

If you have more columns to sort by then keeping adding `OR` clauses to handle tie breaks and select the "best" row for each `ip_address`. Regardless how complicated your subquery is or how many "`SORT BY`~ conditions you have, you will only need one `LEFT JOIN` with this technique.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
l.`ip_address` , l.`status`
FROM
  `logs` l 
GROUP BY l.`ip_address` 
ORDER BY l.`status` = 1 DESC
```

Comment: _never_ `SELECT *` when grouping results. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697469/mysql-what-happens-to-non-aggregated-fields-upon-a-group-by/31697752#31697752