# MIN & MAX with a few JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, union, minmax

I'm trying to display both MIN & MAX while joining a few tables for their information. I'm getting the MIN & MAX but it's showing the wrong info for my other fields.

```
SELECT
    SONG.SONG_NAME,
    ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
    ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
    MAX(SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS) AS LENGTH
FROM SONG
    JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
    JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID
UNION
SELECT
    SONG.SONG_NAME,
    ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
    ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
    MIN(SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS)
FROM SONG
    JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
    JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID;
```

These are the results I'm getting with the query:

```
| SONG_NAME              | ALBUM_NAME                | ARTIST_NAME    | LENGTH |
+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+--------+
| Fluorescent Adolescent | Favourite Worst Nightmare | Arctic Monkeys |    390 |
| Fluorescent Adolescent | Favourite Worst Nightmare | Arctic Monkeys |    177 |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: What happens to non-aggregated fields upon a GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697469/mysql-what-happens-to-non-aggregated-fields-upon-a-group-by)

Comment: I suggest you read the post that @lc. mentioned. Then it would be helpful if you could say what the expected result of the query is as that could help someone give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the MAX & MIN from the SELECT and add a TOP 1 instead. Then add an ORDER BY SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS to get the shortest song and an ORDER BY SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS DESC to get the longest song.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    SONG.SONG_NAME,
    ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
    ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
    SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS AS LENGTH
FROM SONG
    JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
    JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID
ORDER BY SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1
    SONG.SONG_NAME,
    ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
    ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
    SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS AS LENGTH
FROM SONG
    JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
    JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID;
ORDER BY SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS
```

Comment: OP Is using MySQL, not SQL. MySQL does not support `TOP`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are looking for the min and max duration for a song for each artist and album  and for these songs get the song_name

You  could use the union of the grouped  by   SONG.ALBUM_ID,ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME, ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME 
joined  with song for obtain the correct song name

```
select song.song_name, t.ALBUM_NAME, t.ARTIST_NAME, t.LENGTH
from song
inner join (
  SELECT 
      SONG.ALBUM_ID
      ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
      ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
      MAX(SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS) AS LENGTH
  FROM SONG
      JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
      JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID 
  GROUP BY SONG.ALBUM_ID,ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME, ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME
) T on song.album_id = t.album_id and t.LENGTH = song.LENGTH_SECONDS 

UNION 

select song.song_name, t.ALBUM_NAME, t.ARTIST_NAME, t.LENGTH
from song
inner join (
  SELECT 
      SONG.ALBUM_ID
      ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
      ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME,
      MIN(SONG.LENGTH_SECONDS) AS LENGTH
  FROM SONG
      JOIN ALBUM ON ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = SONG.ALBUM_ID
      JOIN ARTIST ON ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = SONG.ARTIST_ID 
  GROUP BY SONG.ALBUM_ID,ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME, ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME
) T on song.album_id = t.album_id and t.LENGTH = song.LENGTH_SECONDS
```